# Community user seems to have started to post comments since ~ Aug 26?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-user

It seems since a few days the [Community user bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has started to post comments to certain questions and answers on several sites. Interestingly, these are comments for which I would expect a certain degree of "understanding" of the question's or answer's content on which the comment was applied, it asks posters to add additional details or to edit a question to make it more specific / focussed.

Can someone provide some background information for this? Has the A.I. behind this bot recently changed? Was this intentionally? And how does this bot assess wether a post needs additional information or has to be more specific?

I [searched this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bcommunity-user%5D%20comment%20is%3Aquestion) on this topic but could not find anything so far.

Comment: From the review change announcement: *Reviewers are encouraged to leave comments for the post-author, but now they can also choose from a few options of canned feedback which will **appear as a comment from the Community account***.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the connection, wihch for me wasn't easy to find (and I guess others may had a similar experience). For someone only seeing the Community user's comments, and not participating here regularly on Meta, it looks really astonishing.

Comment: I agree, however the announcement about the change is featured, which means it appears in the bulletin of all sites, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/paRLf.png :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2: maybe someone should add the community-user tag to that question - otherwise this will be really hard to find, especially in the future. Or, simply, leave my question here, so it helps other's to find the connection to the review queues.

Comment: Your question isn't going to be automatically deleted, all good. (Roomba skips questions closed as duplicate, since they're not off topic)